# Error message "Parse Issue Expected identified or ‘(‘ "

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

I am working through a tutorial for a chat messaging app. I typed in the code in the ViewController.m but I am getting these error messages:

> Parse Issue Expected identified or ‘(‘

(for the 1st bold line in the code below) and

> Semantic Issue Method definition for ‘initNetworkCommunication’ not
>   found

(for the 2nd bold line in the code below)

How can I resolve these issues? Note: I am using Xcode 6.4

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

**- (void)initNetworkCommunication; {**  
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@ 192.168.99.2, 80, &read-Stream,&writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoop-Mode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSDefaultRunLoop-Mode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
}
@end

**@implementation ViewController**

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)joinChat:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Make this:

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication; {
```

This:

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
```

And move this:

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {  
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@ 192.168.99.2, 80, &read-Stream,&writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoop-Mode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSDefaultRunLoop-Mode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
}
```

Below this:

```
@implementation ViewController
```

Comment: When I applied your suggested changes I got error 3 alert messages from Xcode. 1st alert message for the the line which states CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost the message is "Unexpected interface name 'NSStream': expected expression" 2nd alert message at the line which states [inputStream  scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop} the message is "Use of undeclared identifier 'Mode'" and the 3rd and final alert message at the line which states [outputStream  scheduleInRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] the message is "Use of undeclared identifier 'Mode'"

Answer (score -1):

You want to take out the semi-colon in this line:

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication; {
```

It's just not proper syntax having that there.

Comment: The semicolon is actually valid (pointless, but valid). The problem is having the method implementation in the class extension.